# Как отловить Access Violation?

Tags: delphi

У меня в программе (серверное приложение), очень редко, но вылетает **Access Violation**. Не могу разобраться почему. Можно точно определить где ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте помощника: [JCL Debug](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl) (бесплатный, OpenSource), [madExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) (бесплатный для некоммерческого использования), [EurekaLog](https://www.eurekalog.com/) (полностью платный) - они сгенерируют вам подробный стек вызовов и номер строки с AV.

Далее, анализируя логику программы вокруг точки вылета, можно понять в чём баг. Ну или сделать в этом месте дополнительное логирование входных параметров и проч.